# Hiding the name of the registered user in the title bar of Total Commander

Tags: total-commander

I own a registered version of Total Commander. The problem is that the registered name (which is my real name) is displayed in the title bar. Normally I wouldn't mind, except I need to take care when taking screenshots. Or when streaming. Hiding the name from being displayed in the first place would be simpler.

Is there a way to hide the name?

Answer (score 2):

So I made it for you ;) Download AutoIt from www.autoitscript.com. Install, Run the SciTE editor. Paste this there.

```
$run=1
$winpref="Total Commander"
$newname="Total Commander"
while $run
 if winexists($winpref,"") Then
  $handle=WinGetHandle($winpref,"")
  $currt=wingettitle($handle)
  if $currt<>$newname then
   traytip("updating title","",5)
   WinSetTitle($handle,"",$newname)
  EndIf
 EndIf
 sleep(100)
wend
```

run it by pressing F5 and test. If it works you can compile an EXE file from it by pressing F7

Comment: that traytip is not necessary for it to work of course. And it can be customized for any window and title.